# Assigning a Function to a Class Member

Tags: c#, function, class

**I have a class name "Game":**

(For some background, this class defines a game in a game launcher.)

```
public class Game
{
    private string Name;
    public Game(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public void Install()
    {
          //Insert For Each Member 
    }
}
```

**What I want to be able to do is to assign the function `Install()` individualy for each class member.**

```
Game game1 = new Game(1, "dfsdf");
game1.Install= {/*Insert Code Here*/};
```

**Is there any way to do this in c#?**

(Excuse me if it's called a "Method" in c#, I don't really know)

the purpose of this is to be able to assign a different installation procedure for each game.

Comment: `public Action Install { get; set; }`

Comment: I think it's not possible. All that you can do is implement an abstract method Install and then inherit from Game and implement this method. All of this not on runtime of course.

Comment: Have you considered [Strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to accomplish here, but what you could do is make `Install` a property of the type `Action`, then assign an anonymous method to it.

For example:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public Action Install {get; set; }
}

var x = new Foo();
x.Install = () => { 
    // Whatever logic you'd like
};
```

A more common approach would be to create an abstract base class with an abstract method, then implement specific subtypes that provide specific implementation for the method.

Comment: Any method that conforms to the `Action` signature can be used, whether they're anonymous or named doesn't matter.